# CSVを読み込もうとすると「不正な入力がありました」というエラーが出る

Tags: r, csv

```
read.csv("ファイル名", header=T, fileEncoding="utf-8")
```

で読み取りをしようとしたところ、

```
[1] X.
 <0 行> (または長さ 0 の row.names) 
 警告メッセージ: 
1:  read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  で: 
   入力コネクション 'mal.csv' に不正な入力がありました 
2:  read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  で: 
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'mal.csv'
```

のようなエラーがでます。

データは

```
area    walk    old cost
27.2    13  31  5.6
29.7    14  30  6.3
50.2    5   13  9
43  19  10  9.2
37.2    6   9   9.5
46.3    13  8   9.8
39.5    10  12  10
51.8    2   15  11
54.7    2   15  11.3
62.6    2   15  12.5
53.5    8   8   13.1
```

です。（上記はExcelからコピーしましたが、csv形式で保存しているので,区切りになっています）

何が問題か、どう解決するか教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: エラーメッセージに `incomplete final line found by ...` とありますので、`mal.csv` の最終行が改行されていない(ファイルの終わりに改行コードがない)のかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます、先ほどのエラーは出なくなりました。しかし、 read.csv("mal.csv", header=T, fileEncoding="utf-8")
   area.walk.old.cost
1   27.2\t13\t31\t5.6
2   29.7\t14\t30\t6.3
3      50.2\t5\t13\t9
4     43\t19\t10\t9.2
5     37.2\t6\t9\t9.5
6    46.3\t13\t8\t9.8
7    39.5\t10\t12\t10
8     51.8\t2\t15\t11
9   54.7\t2\t15\t11.3
10  62.6\t2\t15\t12.5
11   53.5\t8\t8\t13.1のような結果になってしましました。このｔはどうすれば消せるのでしょうか？何度もすみません。

Comment: 見た所、カンマ区切りではなくてタブ区切りになっていますね。タブだけでなく、スペースでも区切られている様ですので、`read.table("mal.csv", header=T, ...)` とすれば良いかと思いますが、ヘッダ部分(`area.walk.old.cost`)の区切り文字が `.` になっている様に見受けられるのでエラーになってしまいそうです。一度確認して下さい。

Comment: read.tableで完璧にできました！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージに `incomplete final line found by ...` とありますので、 `mal.csv` の最終行が改行されていない(ファイルの終わりに改行コードがない)のかもしれません。

また、見た所、カンマ区切りではなくてタブ区切りになっています。タブだけでなく、スペースでも区切られている様ですので、 `read‌​.table("mal.csv", header=T, ...)` とすれば良いかと思いますが、ヘッダ部分( `area.walk.old.cost` )の区切り文字が `.` になっている様に見受けられるのでエラーになってしまいそうです。一度確認して下さい。

-- [metropolisさん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis)の[コメント1](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33920/csv%E3%82%92%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%82%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8-%E4%B8%8D%E6%AD%A3%E3%81%AA%E5%85%A5%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B#comment33431_33920)、[2](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33920/csv%E3%82%92%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%82%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8-%E4%B8%8D%E6%AD%A3%E3%81%AA%E5%85%A5%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B#comment33435_33920)より