# RでCSVファイルの読み込み時にエラー: 入力コネクション 'Data/Ramen.csv' に不正な入力がありました

Tags: r, csv

Rを最近学び始めた者です。

CSVファイルをRで読み込もうとしたら以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。
解決策をご教授お願い致します。

**コード:**

```
df <- read.csv("Data/Ramen.csv", header=T, fileEncoding="Shift-JIS")
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
1:  read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  で: 
   入力コネクション 'Data/Ramen.csv' に不正な入力がありました 
2:  read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  で: 
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'Data/Ramen.csv'
>
```

Comment: `fileEncoding="Shift-JIS"` とされていますが、`Ramen.csv` のエンコーディングが `UTF-8` だったりはしませんか？

Comment: 重複候補: [RでCSVファイルが読み込めない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/56634)