# Rでcsvファイルを読み込みたいがエラーがでる「入力コネクションには不正な入力があります」

Tags: r, csv

大学でRを使ったデータ解析の授業があり、質問させていただきます。初質問なのでいたらない点などありましたら申し訳ございません。Rについては全くの初心者です。

csvファイルを読み込もうとしているのですが、エラーになってしまいます。

**入力した式**

```r
read.csv("~.csv",fileEncoding="utf-8")
```

**エラー**

```r
read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  でエラー: 
   入力中には利用可能な行がありません 
 追加情報:  警告メッセージ: 
 read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  で: 
   入力コネクション '~.csv' に不正な入力がありました
```

ファイルについては課題ページに添付されていたもの(エクセル)をcsvの形式に変えて保存しました。これはコードが悪いのでしょうか、それともファイルに問題があるのでしょうか。解決方法が分かる方がいらっしゃればご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: 文字エンコーディングを `UTF-8` としていますが、`~.csv` のエンコーディングが `CP-932` だったりしませんか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。エクセルの保存の段階で「csv utf-8 （コンマ区切り）（*.csv）」で保存したのですが、これではいけなかったのでしょうか

Comment: それで問題ないはずです。その他に考えられるのは BOM(Byte Order Mark)が付いているのかもしれないので、`UTF-8-BOM` を指定してみるとよいかもしれません。`read.csv("~.csv",fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")`

Comment: 読み込めました！ありがとうございました！

Comment: 後学のためにBOMとはなんなのか簡単にでいいので教えていただけますでしょうか。「-BOM」が加わることで何が変わったのでしょう。

Comment: `UTF-8` エンコーディングの場合、ファイル(`~.csv`)の先頭に `0xefbbbf` という 3 バイトのデータが付くことがあります。このデータを `BOM` と呼んでいます。説明としては[バイト順マーク](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E9%A0%86%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF)を読んでみて下さい。

Comment: 本当に色々とご丁寧にありがとうございました。非常に助かりました。

Comment: 重複候補: [RでCSVファイルが読み込めない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/56634)

Answer (score 2):

以下は回答ではありませんが、`R` における UTF-8 の BOM(Byte Order Mark)の取扱いについて捕捉しておきます。

`R` で `help(file)` を実行して `Encoding` の項を参照すると、以下の様に説明されています。

> **Encoding**:
>
> As from R 3.0.0 the encoding `"UTF-8-BOM"` is accepted for reading and will remove a Byte Order Mark if present (which **it often is for files and webpages generated by Microsoft applications**). If a BOM is required (it is not recommended) when writing it should be written explicitly, e.g. by `writeChar("\ufeff", con, eos = NULL)` or `writeBin(as.raw(c(0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf)), binary_con)`